# ArcGIS Pro - Route Solver Multiprocessing in Standalone Script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, route, parallel-processing

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9 with an advanced single use license and a local network dataset.

I am attempting to write a standalone script that takes as its input an arbitrary set of origin-destination pairs and produces as its output the travel distance (e.g., driving distance in miles) and time (e.g., driving distance in minutes) for each pair. The script creates and subsequently solves a route analysis layer using the route solver method.

The core logic of the script is as follows:

(1) load the set of origin-destination pairs from an input csv file as a point feature class

```
arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(
 [input csv file]
,[output (origins|destinations) layer name]
,[input (origins|destinations) longitude field], [input (origins|destinations) latitude field])
```

(2) create a new Route_ID field that concatenates the origin ID and destination ID for each pair with a pipe delimiter

```
arcpy.management.CalculateField(
 [(origins|destinations) layer name]
,'Route_ID'
,field_type = 'TEXT'
,expression = [concatenation expression]
,expression_type = 'ARCADE')
```

(3) define a function that loads the origins and destinations for each chunk and then solves for the routes

```
odp_FieldMappings = route.fieldMappings(
    arcpy.nax.RouteInputDataType.Stops
)

odp_FieldMappings['RouteName'].mappedFieldName = 'Route_ID'

def solve_chunk(chunk):
    
    # Define chunk start and end
    chunk_index = chunk - 1
    
    odp_chunk_start = (chunk_index * ChunkSize) + 1
    odp_chunk_end   = odp_chunk_start + (ChunkSize - 1)
    
    # Load chunk origins
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(
         [origins layer name]
        ,gdb
        ,[origins chunk layer name]
        ,f'OBJECTID >= {odp_chunk_start} \
            and \
           OBJECTID <= {odp_chunk_end}')

    route.load( arcpy.nax.RouteInputDataType.Stops
               ,[origins chunk layer name]
               ,odp_FieldMappings
               ,append=False)
    
    # Load chunk destinations
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(
         [destinations layer name]
        ,gdb
        ,[destinations chunk layer name]
        ,f'OBJECTID >= {odp_chunk_start} \
            and \
           OBJECTID <= {odp_chunk_end}')

    route.load( arcpy.nax.RouteInputDataType.Stops
               ,[destinations chunk layer name]
               ,odp_FieldMappings
               ,append=True)

    # Solve
    return (chunk, route.solve())
```

(4) feed this function into a multiprocessing pool to generate the solve results

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map_async(solve_chunk, chunks)
```

However, frustratingly, I just can't seem to get the multiprocessing to work. When I attempt to call the solve_chunk function within map_async(), I get a 000732 error when loading the chunk origins:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset [origins layer name] does not exist or is not supported
```

And sure enough, when I check my project's geodatabase, I don't see the expected feature classes.

I've tried multiple ways without success to fix this issue, including using different ArcPy functions (e.g., `arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer`). But nothing seems to work. I've used ArcGIS for years, but running scripts in a standalone environment rather than via the Python window is new to me, as is multiprocessing.

How can I do this?

P.S., here are my environment settings:

```
ArcGIS_ProjFolder = aprx.homeFolder
m                 = aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]
gdb               = aprx.defaultGeodatabas
arcpy.env.workspace       = gdb
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

Comment: I would say because you have deliberately redacted your code its impossible for anyone to answer this question as may be the error lies within the redacted section and say not a bug in the logic? If you want anyone to help provide the real code with real layer names and expressions.

Comment: @Hornbydd I understand your point. I used the generic references to make the code more compact since some of the steps are repeated once for origins and once for destinations. It already felt like a lot of code for people to review. I can provide real names if people feel strongly, but what I'm looking for is an evaluation of the logic. I'm certain that is where the fault lies, rather than in a mistaken layer name or table reference.